# Usage of suffix "-some"

Tags: word-usage

Normally, Can we use -some after noun/adjectives for the meaning of tending to? such as mansome, girlsome, computersome.

Comment: First you need to look look at a dictionary of derivations.  You will find that ‘-some’ coms from German -sam, via old English -sum.  Theoretically, you can coin any adjective you like by adding ‘-some’ to a noun.  But if you do so, it is a courtesy to signal the fact by placing it in single quotes.  Be aware also that there is a host of other adjectival suffixes.

Comment: The few adjectives ending in -some (e.g. winsome, gladsome) are old-fashioned or literary and not in everyday use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A correct method that always works is to add -like

- Computer -> computerlike
- Boy -> boylike
- Woman -> womanlike

But sometimes there is a shorter form:

- Boyish
- Womanly

If this shorter form exists, it will usually be listed somewhere under the dictionary entry of the noun